# What is the relationship between SBT, the scala compiler and the scala SDK?

Tags: scala

If I have it correct, the SDK is just a bunch of common jars which are often used in scala projects, SBT is the build tool which also contains the scala compiler?

A project needs to have access to the SDK which is given by the Scalahome path?

Is that correct?

Comment: SBT a build tool which can be used to make scala projects (think Maven). It does not contain the scala compiler but can be configured to download it. The SDK contains the Scala libraries and the scala compiler. This might be useful for you: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Configuring-Scala.html

Comment: @I.K. isn't SBT downloads scala compiler for each of our projects *by default*?

Comment: @om-nom-nom, as you know, if SBT is run without a build.sbt file present, it will download the scala compiler and the scala library so that you can run REPL sessions at least. If it is invoked with a build.sbt file present it will pick up the version of the scala compiler from there, and download it if it is not in the local repository. So in either case, downloading the compiler by default as you expressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution from scala-lang.org contains various modules, including the compiler and standard library.

The command line tools, scalac and scala, put all those jars on the class path by default. When you start the REPL (by running `scala`), for example, the `scala.swing` package is on the class path.

The `sbt` build tool requires you to specify all dependencies and then downloads them. Alternatively, it's possible to specify a local Scala distro to use.

Also, `sbt` itself is both a launcher that bootstraps the build and the tool that runs the build, which can be an arbitrary version of `sbt`. In addition, the version of the compiler used to build the project can be set on a project basis.

Although `sbt` and the compiler are functionally decoupled in this way, they are at least as coupled at the source level as the compiler and the IDE. (There are comments in the compiler source to the effect, "SBT still uses this.")

Moreover, it's generally acknowledged that the compiler relies on incremental compilation for a high-quality developer experience. The activator tool, as a gateway tool, relies on sbt.

In this sense, sbt is not just a wrapper for the compiler tool, but is key to its usability.

You can get by with just an sbt project, or just an IDE workspace. You can run the REPL from sbt or in an IDE worksheet.

I like to run the REPL from an arbitrary directory, and I keep an ash heap of snippets on which to run scalac, so I always have a shell alias for my current distro. If only sbt had an option to run itself in a "clean room" tmp directory. Maybe `sbt-extras` offers that.